# Is there a way in CSS to get the height (or other property) of an element and share that same value with properties of other elements?

Tags: css, frontend

For example, I have a navigation bar that sticks to the top of my page (like the one on Stackoverflow).

Therefore, the padding-top of the body should be set to the exact height the navigation bar is.

However, this navigation bar changes in height from time to time, so I can't rely on an absolute value like 70px to assign to the padding-top value of the body.

So, what I'm looking for is a CSS-pure way to make sure this padding-top is always the same value.

I also can't use var(), because I don't know in advance what height the navigation bar will end up as.

Thanks.

Comment: There may be other methods for accomplishing the layout you want. You should post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript not css but anyway there may be other methods as @Michael B said.

with javascript you can do:

```
var nav = document.getElementById("navigationID");
console.log(nav.clientHeight); 
// nav.clientHeight will return integer value of your navigation height.
```

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("navigationID");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

container.style.paddingTop = nav.clientHeight + "px";
```

```css
#navigationID
{
  color:#000;
  height:70px;
  width:100%;
  border:4px solid green;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}

#container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="navigationID"> navigation </div>
<div id="container">
    container
</div>
</body>
</html>
```